# How to append JSON response to HTML grid

Tags: javascript, json, pagespeed

How do I append this `JSON` data to e.g. `Grid` layout.

I'm pulling `Google PageSpeed JSON` data through following script:

```js
function clicked () {
  const url = document.getElementById('url').value;

  document.getElementById('urlerror').style.display = 'none';

  if (url.indexOf('https://') === -1) {
    document.getElementById('urlerror').style.display = 'block';
    return;
  }

  const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.open('GET', `https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=${encodeURIComponent(url)}&fields=lighthouseResult%2Fcategories%2F*%2Fscore&prettyPrint=false&strategy=desktop&category=performance&category=pwa&category=best-practices&category=accessibility&category=seo&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`);

  xhr.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById('data').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
  }

  xhr.send();
}
```

The JSON data is sent to the following `div`:

```html
<div class="pagespeed">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Enter webpage URL e.g.http://www.example.com" id="url" />
    <input type="button" id="button" value="PageSpeed Data" onclick="clicked();" />
    <div id="urlerror">Please Enter a Valid URL e.g. http://www.example.com</div>
    <pre id="data"></pre>
</div>
```

This is the JSON data. Categories remain the same but scores are dynamic:

```
{
  "lighthouseResult": {
    "categories": {
      "performance": {
        "score": 0.99
      },
      "accessibility": {
        "score": 0.7
      },
      "best-practices": {
        "score": 0.77
      },
      "seo": {
        "score": 0.9
      },
      "pwa": {
        "score": 0.56
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'd like to see 2 columns, with categories on the left and the scores on the right. Each category and score has its own id or class inside the HTML

Comment: You might need to create a table element inside your <pre> tag. And within your function, filter your response into key value pairs and put keys and values inside seperate <td> tags of the table. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this:

```js
function renderTable (json) {
  console.log(json)
  // TODO: remove dummy data! and set data from json!
  const data = {
    "lighthouseResult": {
      "categories": {
        "performance": {
          "score": 0.99
        },
        "accessibility": {
          "score": 0.7
        },
        "best-practices": {
          "score": 0.77
        },
        "seo": {
          "score": 0.9
        },
        "pwa": {
          "score": 0.56
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  const { categories } = data.lighthouseResult
  
  const table = document.createElement('table')
  const trHeading = document.createElement('tr')
  const thCategory = document.createElement('th')
  
  trHeading.classList = 'category-heading'
    
  thCategory.innerText = 'Category'
  thCategory.classList = 'category-key-heading'

  trHeading.appendChild(thCategory)

  const thScore = document.createElement('th')

  thScore.innerText = 'Score'
  thScore.classList = 'category-value-heading'

  trHeading.appendChild(thScore)

  table.appendChild(trHeading)
  
  Object.keys(categories).forEach(category => {
    const tr = document.createElement('tr')
    
    tr.classList = 'category category-' + category
    
    const tdKey = document.createElement('td')
    
    tdKey.innerText = category
    tdKey.classList = 'category-key category-key-' + category
    
    tr.appendChild(tdKey)

    const tdValue = document.createElement('td')
    
    tdValue.innerText = categories[category].score
    tdValue.classList = 'category-value category-value-' + category
    
    tr.appendChild(tdValue)
  
    table.appendChild(tr)
  })
  
  const out = document.getElementById("data")

  out.innerHTML = ''
  out.appendChild(table)
}

function clicked() {
  document.getElementById("urlerror").style.display = 'none';
  var url = document.getElementById("url").value;
  if (url.indexOf('https://') === -1) { document.getElementById("urlerror").style.display = 'block'; return; }
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
  xhr.open("GET", "https://www.googleapis.com/pagespeedonline/v5/runPagespeed?url=" + encodeURIComponent(url) + "&fields=lighthouseResult%2Fcategories%2F*%2Fscore&prettyPrint=false&strategy=desktop&category=performance&category=pwa&category=best-practices&category=accessibility&category=seo&key={YOUR_API_KEY}")
  xhr.onload = function () {
    // document.getElementById("data").innerHTML = xhr.responseText
    renderTable(xhr.response)
  }
  xhr.send()
}
```

```html
<div class="pagespeed">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Enter webpage URL e.g.http://www.example.com" id="url" value="https://google.de" />
  <input type="button" id="button" value="PageSpeed Data" onclick="clicked();" />
  <div id="urlerror">Please Enter a Valid URL e.g. http://www.example.com</div>
  <div id="data"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Template String ES6 for write html in js.

```js
const template = document.getElementById("data");
const data = {
  lighthouseResult: {
    categories: {
      performance: {
        score: 0.99
      },
      accessibility: {
        score: 0.7
      },
      "best-practices": {
        score: 0.77
      },
      seo: {
        score: 0.9
      },
      pwa: {
        score: 0.56
      }
    }
  }
};

const categories = data.lighthouseResult.categories;

template.innerHTML = `
                      <div class="item-data">Performance</div>
                      <div class="item-data">
                      ${categories.performance.score}
                      </div>
                      <div class="item-data">Accessibility</div>
                      <div class="item-data">
                      ${categories.accessibility.score}
                      </div>
                      <div class="item-data">Best Practices</div>
                      <div class="item-data">
                      ${categories["best-practices"].score}
                      </div>
                      <div class="item-data">SEO</div>
                      <div class="item-data">
                      ${categories.seo.score}
                      </div>
                      <div class="item-data">PWA</div>
                      <div class="item-data">
                      ${categories.pwa.score}
                      </div>
                      `;
```

```css
 #data {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 50% 50%;
      grid-gap: 0.5rem;
      padding: 0.5rem;
    }
    .item-data {
      border-bottom: 1px solid #eeeeee;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app">
      <div id="data"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thnx but the JSON data is dynamic. The scores are always different. How do I handle that?